# Get Nearest non-None Item in List

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I need to find a way of, having an `array` and an `index`, get the nearest non-None value of the item in that index.

For example:

```
array = [4, 5, 1, None, 9, None, 7, 8]
index = 4
```

I need to get the nearest integers of `array[index]` **on the left and on the right**:

```
print(array[index])
# 9
```

Expected output:

```
on_left = 1
on_right = 7
```

**CURRENT SOLUTION**

This is what I have:

```
value = array[index]
new_array = [val for val in array if val]                                                                        
print(new_array)
# [4, 5, 1, 4, 7, 8]
                                                                                                                   
new_array.index(value)
# 0
```

*Then I would use that index to get the right and left items

The issue here, as you can see, happens when there are repeated numbers, In this example I'm getting the index of the first `4` instead of the second, how would you solve this?

Comment: I already solve these issues, thanks for letting me know this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the next function on a subset of the array starting at the next position going forward (for the right side) and at the previous position, going backwards (for the left side):

```
array    = [4, 5, 1, None, 4, None, 7, 8]
index    = 4
on_right = next(v for v in array[index+1:]    if v is not None)
on_left  = next(v for v in array[index-1::-1] if v is not None)

print(on_left,on_right) # 1 7
```